# input sources missing ubuntu "21.10"

Tags: input-language

I'm trying to install the Japanese keyboard and I've gone through basically all the steps required but when I accesed
"Region & Language" the input source option wasn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

日本語を入力するためには To input Japanese properly

- font
- input-engine

の2つが必要です You need to install these two, too.

フォントはシステムに最初から入っていたり日本語環境を構築しようとすると自動的にインストールされます Japanese fonts are installed by default or automatically.

エンジンの方はユーザーの好みにより選択できます You can choose input engine you like.

`sudo apt install ibus-mozc`
`sudo apt install fcitx-mozc`
`sudo apt install ibus-anthy`

最初の `ibus` `fcitx` などは入力方式の名前でエンジンのインターフェイス部分です first part of the engine e.g. `ibus` or `fcitx` is an interface name.

後半の `mozc` `anthy` はエンジン名です `mozc`はGoogle日本語変換を基に作られていて優秀です `anthy` は古くからある unix&linux 用の日本語変換として大変有名ですが開発は滞りがちで語彙や効率は悪いですがインターフェイスとの相性は良いと思います Last part is an engine itself, mozc from Google and anthy from Kyoto univ.

note: If you are a professional Japanese typer or so, you can install ATOK X3, it offers more accurate conversion which it has been doing more than 3 decades. Link here
[ATOKのことも忘れないで](https://luxion.jp/2020/04/ubuntu-20-04%E3%81%A7atok-x3%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86/)

Answer (score 1):

The Input Sources section was moved in Ubuntu 21.10 from *Region & Language* to *Keyboard*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, if there is only one input method (for example only Japanese Mozc) in the "input source" of "Keyboard", the input sources selector disappears from the menu bar (which might makes sense, but without this in the menu bar, kana/hiragana/romaji change isn't easy). Please make sure to have some languages there. (Maybe put three inputs: japanese mozc, japanese, english)

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).